# How do i make that the rectangle first location will be the mouse cursor location and end point will be where i leave the mouse left button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
            {
                if (btn == true)
                {
                    if (Rect != null && Rect.Width > 0 && Rect.Height > 0)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, Rect);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (btn == true)
            {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                return;
            Point tempEndPoint = e.Location;
            Rect.Location = new Point(
                Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, tempEndPoint.X),
                Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, tempEndPoint.Y));
            Rect.Size = new Size(
                Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - tempEndPoint.X),
                Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - tempEndPoint.Y));

                pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            btn = !btn;
        }
```

What i want to do is two things:

1. When i click first time the mouse left button the `RectStartPoint X` and `Y` should be where the mouse cursor is now. Then i move the mouse the rectangle get bigger or smaller and then when i click again on the mouse left button leave the rectangle as it on the size where last the mouse cursor was. How can i od it ?
   Now it all the time start at **0,0** the `RectStartPoint` will be **0,0** and if i change it to `e.Location.X` and `Y` instead `RectStartPoint` it won't draw anything.
2. Second thing is when i click first time the left mouse button and change the rectangle size if i will keep move the mouse and at the same time click again on the left mouse button the rectangle will gone/delete. If i will not move the mouse only left click button the rectangle will stay. Why if i move the mouse and click left button at the same time the rectangle is deleted ?

Comment: you should store the position of the mouse to a class level variable (property) in the `MouseDown` and use it as starting point in the `MouseMove` event as start point

Comment: bansi this is working thanks stored and it's working great. And the second problem or maybe it's normal if i move the mouse when it's drawing/showing the rectangle very fast and click the leftm ouse button the rectangle is gone/delete. Whay is that ? If im drawing the rectangle and slowly click again the button left mouse button the rectangle stay as it is. But if im clicking left mouse button when moving the mouse fast the rectangle is delete.

Comment: I have never tried drawing on the mouse move event, `pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();` redraws the picturebox.  I would have normally drawn the rectangle in the `Paint` event of `pictureBoxSnap`. I would just store the rectangle points, and is there a need to draw a rectangle, in the `MouseMove` event instead of drawing.

Comment: bansi The draw it self is in the paint event already. If i'm removing the invalidate from the move event then it will never get to the paint event. Where should i put/add the invalidate of the pictureBox ?

Comment: `if (Rect != null && Rect.Width > 0 && Rect.Height > 0)` prevents the drawing after you have clicked without moving. Now, what __should__ happen when you do that?? Should the Rectangle go away, should it change or should nothing happen at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want from your question. The code below does the classic rubberbanding: It paints a live rectangle and deletes it when you click without moving.

I put the calculation in a flexible function.

```
bool btn = false;
Point RectStartPoint = Point.Empty;
Point RectEndPoint = Point.Empty;

private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
    {
        {
            Rectangle Rect = getRect(RectStartPoint, RectEndPoint); ;
            if (Rect != Rectangle.Empty)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, Rect);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (btn == true)
    {
        RectEndPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    RectStartPoint = e.Location;
    btn = true;
}

private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    btn = false;
    RectEndPoint = e.Location;
    pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
}

Rectangle getRect(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    Point p = new Point(Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X),Math.Min(p1.Y, p2.Y) );
    Size s = new Size(Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y));
    return new Rectangle(p, s);
}
```

Note 1: The PictureBox control is already doublebuffered, so it doesn't flicker, no matter how fast or big you draw.

Note 2: You might need to do a more thoruogh mouse button check if the right (or middle) buttons could get involved. Here is an example for the 'proper' check:

```
if (e.Button & MouseButtons.Left != MouseButtons.None)  ..
```