# Resize and move a drawn rectangle in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, rectangles

I am trying to move and resize a drawn rectangle using mouse events, the new starting location of x, y is calculated but the rectangle position doesn't update:
My form source code:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    Rectangle rect;
    Point StartXY;
    Point EndXY;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;

    bool m_mouseDown = false;
    bool m_movingRect = false;


    Pen rectPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gObj = e.Graphics;

        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, height, width);
        rectPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
        gObj.DrawRectangle(rectPen, rect);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        m_mouseDown = true;

        // Moving rectangle
        if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            m_movingRect = true;
            Console.WriteLine("m_mouseDown");
        }

        StartXY = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
        else
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        if (m_mouseDown && rect.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            rect.X += e.X - StartXY.X;    // <---- it is calculated correctly but doesn't update rectangle position
            rect.Y += e.Y - StartXY.Y;


            StartXY = e.Location;
            Console.WriteLine("pictureBox1_MouseMove StartXY " + StartXY.X);
            Console.WriteLine("pictureBox1_MouseMove StartXY " + StartXY.Y);
            Console.WriteLine("pictureBox1_MouseMove rect " + rect.X);
            Console.WriteLine("pictureBox1_MouseMove rect " + rect.Y);
        }

        if (m_mouseDown && !rect.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            EndXY = e.Location;

            x = Math.Min(StartXY.X, EndXY.X);
            y = Math.Min(StartXY.Y, EndXY.Y);

            height = Math.Abs(StartXY.X - EndXY.X);
            width = Math.Abs(StartXY.Y - EndXY.Y);
            //Console.WriteLine("pictureBox1_MouseMove XXXX: " + " --- " + e.X.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine("pictureBox1_MouseMove YYYY: " + " --- " + e.Y.ToString());
        }

        Invalidate(true);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_movingRect)
        {
            EndXY = e.Location;
        }

        m_mouseDown = false;
        m_movingRect = false;

        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find this [resizable movable control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774101/3110834) useful.

Comment: @RezaAghaei It is useful but I want to learn from mistakes, that is why I am seeking for guides.