# Drawing over resized control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, custom-controls

I am implementing a screenshot in my application, with the user being able to select which part will be captured, for this purpose, i created a control to overlay a Picturebox using the example provided in this Link:
[Creating Custom Picturebox with Draggable and Resizable Selection Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756981/creating-custom-picturebox-with-draggable-and-resizable-selection-window)

The control works well, doing what needs to be done, but what I'm having difficulty implementing is that when the user clicks on a button outside the control, it would no longer be moved, changing its cursor from SizeAll to Arrow, but could still be resizable.

How can I perform such a task?

This is the code I'm using now to create my control

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ControlSizable
{
    public partial class FrameControl: UserControl
    {
       public FrameControl()
       {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (var p = new Pen(Color.White , 3))
        {
            p.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
        }
    }
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20;
    const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0xA3;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        int borderWidth = 10;
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR)  /*Setting cursor to SizeAll*/
        {
            if ((m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff) == 0x2 /*Move*/)
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.SizeAll;
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
        
        }
        if ((m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)) /*Disable Mazimiz on Double click*/
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
        {
            var pos = PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff,
                m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16));
            if (pos.X <= ClientRectangle.Left + borderWidth &&
                pos.Y <= ClientRectangle.Top + borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(13); //TOPLEFT
            else if (pos.X >= ClientRectangle.Right - borderWidth &&
                pos.Y <= ClientRectangle.Top + borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(14); //TOPRIGHT
            else if (pos.X <= ClientRectangle.Left + borderWidth &&
                pos.Y >= ClientRectangle.Bottom - borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(16); //BOTTOMLEFT
            else if (pos.X >= ClientRectangle.Right - borderWidth &&
                pos.Y >= ClientRectangle.Bottom - borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(17); //BOTTOMRIGHT
            else if (pos.X <= ClientRectangle.Left + borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(10); //LEFT
            else if (pos.Y <= ClientRectangle.Top + borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(12); //TOP
            else if (pos.X >= ClientRectangle.Right - borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(11); //RIGHT
            else if (pos.Y >= ClientRectangle.Bottom - borderWidth)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(15); //Bottom
            else
                m.Result = new IntPtr(2); //Move
        }
    }
}
```

}

Example of a screenshot using the control:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is that when the user clicks on the arrow button, the control is no longer moved around the screen, just resized by the edges and I can draw the arrow in the drawing itself (This process of drawing the arrow, I can already do it)

Comment: Last else clause for the WM_NCHITTEST handler.  Don't return 2 if the button is active.

Comment: ^^ and don't handle the `WM_SETCURSOR`. You'd add a couple of `bool` properties (say `Sizable` & `Movable`) to enable/disable sizing and/or moving the frame.

Comment: @Hans Passant How could I pass the message to the control that the button is active?

Comment: @dr.null If I don't manipulate WM_SETCURSOR, how could I move it around my form?

Comment: 1) _How could I pass the message to the control that the button is active?_ I told you how. Add public properties. 2) _If I don't manipulate WM_SETCURSOR, how could I move it around my form?_ You move the Frame when you set `m.Result = new IntPtr(2);`. Handling the `WM_SETCURSOR` does not move anything. You just change the cursor in there. So, you don't need to change the cursor to indicate that the frame is not movable.

Comment: @HansPassant and Dr.Null Thank you very much for your help, now my process is working very well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a public `bool` Property to the Custom Control, here named `CanMove`, defaults to `true`.

Then, in the WndProc override, when the message is `WM_SETCURSOR`, you evaluate `CanMove`: if it's the default value (`true`), you set the Cursor to `Cursors.SizeAll`, otherwise to `Cursors.Arrow` (or whatever you see fit)

When the message is `WM_NCHITTEST`, in the last `if` condition, if CanMove is `true`  you return `(IntPtr)2`, otherwise `IntPtr.Zero`.

Add `using System.ComponentModel;` on top of the FrameControl class file.

The Control is still resizable when `CanMove` is `false`.

So, when you click that Button, just set the `CanMove` Property of the Framecontrol to `false`.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class FrameControl : Control {
    public FrameControl() { // [...]}

    [DefaultValue(true)] 
    public bool CanMove { get; set; } = true;

    // [...]

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR)  /*Setting cursor to SizeAll or Arrow */
        {
            if ((m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff) == 0x2 /*Move*/) {
                Cursor.Current = CanMove ? Cursors.SizeAll : Cursors.Arrow;
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
        }
        // [...]
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST) {
            // [...]
            if (pos.X <= ClientRectangle.Left + borderWidth &&
                pos.Y <= ClientRectangle.Top + borderWidth)
                m.Result = (IntPtr)13; //TOPLEFT
            // [...]
            else
                m.Result = CanMove ? (IntPtr)2 : IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's perfect, it works very well.... but it caused another problem, I can't draw the arrow on the control. I added the process to draw the arrow in the control's MouseMove, MouseUp and MouseDown, but I was not successful, is this correct? tks again

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. If you want to paint onto the surface of a Control, you have to handle its `Paint` event and use the Graphics object provided by `PaintEventArgs`. See the example here: [How to use the Paint event to draw shapes at mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708936/7444103)

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, I already understand what is happening with my control and I know how to solve it, but thank you very much for your help, the process is working perfectly now.......