# C# Winform Panel clear / fully update --- used for mouse multiple selection

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, panel, c#-3.0

I want to select some structures (polygons and rectangles) in a panel. I have used the new `ExtendedPanel` Class, for the opacity of the mouse panel.
`panel1` is for the structure, `extendedPanel1` is for the selected area of the mouse. (`SetSelectionRect()` ist the set of the selections area)

In the figure below, the red is the graph I drew on panel1, and the green is the rectangle selected by the mouse. In fact, it should present a green rectangle, which is the rectangle when the mouse selection ends, but now there are many. This shows that the transparency setting in the `extendetPanel1` works after `extendedPanel1.Invalidate();`, but the historical rectangle drawn does not disappear.

Can you please tell me, how should I write the code for the mouse selection in the Panel?

I actually want to realize some polygons and editing. I drew some polygons (rectangles) in `panel1`, and now I want to use the mouse to select some parts and make some changes (such as deleting some polygons).
My thoughts on this are: Draw the polygons on `panel1`, and `panel2` displays the selection by the mouse, but the bottom of `panel2` is transparent.

Then, according to the coordinate calculation, etc., it is judged whether the geometric figure in `panel1` is in the area selected in `panel2`.  If it is, then I will delete it. I don’t know if my thoughts are reasonable.
If you can provide a suitable solution, I am very grateful.

[image: Sample image]

code of extendetpanel:

```
public class ExtendedPanel : Panel
{
    private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    public ExtendedPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    }

    private int opacity = 0;
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Opacity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.opacity;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 100)
                throw new ArgumentException("value must be between 0 and 100");
            this.opacity = value;
        }
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(this.opacity * 255 / 100, this.BackColor)))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Code of paint and events:

```
        private void extendedPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnPaint(e);           

        extendedPanel1.Opacity = 0;
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, 1F))
            {
                pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, selection);
            }
        }
        
    }

    private void extendedPanel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        selectionStart = extendedPanel1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    private void extendedPanel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
        SetSelectionRect();
        extendedPanel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void extendedPanel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!mouseDown)
            return;
        selectionEnd = extendedPanel1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        SetSelectionRect();
        extendedPanel1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! `Can you please tell me, how should I write the code for the mouse selection in the panel?`, what specific issue are you having?

Comment: Did you register the events using '+='?

Comment: You really should avoid calling `base.OnPaint(e);` in an event handler, that call belongs to the `OnPaint()` override. You should invalidate the Control if you change the opacity level. It's not clear what `SetSelectionRect()` is doing (just sets `selection`?) Ext: you don't need `PointToClient(MousePosition)`, `MouseEventArgs` already gives you the location. `mouseDown` is also not needed, you should check whether the left mouse button is down. You should probably use a PictureBox instead of a Panel for this (long to explain). More...

Comment: Not sure what you want. A non-persistent [rubberband](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348678/how-do-i-make-that-the-rectangle-first-location-will-be-the-mouse-cursor-locatio/25349796#25349796) rectangle?

Comment: Due to the word limit, I directly described it in the answer area.

Comment: '+=':  I did not use this for the events. Should I use this one?

Comment: @Jimi 
In a transparent panel, can the panel be fully initialized by invalid controls? Now even if I initialize it now, the rectangle drawn before is still there. SetselectionsRect()  is the area selected by the mouse. Could you please give me a better suggestion?

Comment: [How to determine when Rectangles overlap or intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62948409/7444103). Combine with: [How to use the Paint event to draw shapes at mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708936/7444103)

Comment: You can use [ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe?view=netcore-3.1) to draw your "rubberband".  If you draw the EXACT SAME rectangle over the previous one, then it is erased.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62903203/2330053) of what rubberbanding could look like.

Comment: @Jimi Actually, those are implemented on the form, I need to implement it on the geometric figures drawn by the panel, so the form method is not suitable

Comment: All drawings work the same way, it doesn't matter much what is the surface. What is important is to handle a collection of shapes and use the appropriate methods (`Rectangle.Intersects()`/`IntersectsWith()`, `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` etc.) to determine when a shape intersects/is contained in another. After that, it's all quite simple (or it will be, after some testing :). If you want to draw rubber-bands, as Idle_Mind mentioned, you can also draw a rectangle without adding it to a collection of shapes, so next time you Invalidate the *canvas* it will *disappear*.

Comment: @Jimi You are right, but the problem now is: The rubber-bands I want to draw is on a panel (panel1), so the ldle_Mind method is not suitable, because the method of drawing directly on the Form.